# How do I tell a VS Package that I want to subscribe to IDTExtensibility2

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, add-in, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to create a VS2013 extension so I can be notified of a build event.

I create a VS Package and I have a sample `Connect` class the implements `IDTExtensibility2` and has the code I need in it for the `OnBuildProjConfigBegin` event.

How do I tell the package to use the class?

My Connect class is as follows for reference but I think I need to change something elsewhere to get this to work:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars
Imports Extensibility
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Connect

    Implements IDTExtensibility2


    Private _applicationObject As DTE2
    Private _addInInstance As AddIn
    Private _buildEvents As BuildEvents

    '''<summary>Implements the constructor for the Add-in object. Place your initialization code within this method.</summary>
    Public Sub New()
        MessageBox.Show("New")
    End Sub

    '''<summary>Implements the OnConnection method of the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Receives notification that the Add-in is being loaded.</summary>
    '''<param name='application'>Root object of the host application.</param>
    '''<param name='connectMode'>Describes how the Add-in is being loaded.</param>
    '''<param name='addInInst'>Object representing this Add-in.</param>
    '''<remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode As ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection
        MessageBox.Show("Connection")
        _applicationObject = CType(application, DTE2)
        _addInInstance = CType(addInInst, AddIn)
        _buildEvents = _applicationObject.Events.BuildEvents
        AddHandler _buildEvents.OnBuildBegin, AddressOf OnBuildBegin
        AddHandler _buildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigBegin, AddressOf OnBuildProjConfigBegin
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnBuildProjConfigBegin(ByVal project As String, ByVal projectConfig As String, ByVal platform As String, ByVal solutionConfig As String)
        MessageBox.Show("Build has begun")
    End Sub

    '''<summary>Implements the OnDisconnection method of the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Receives notification that the Add-in is being unloaded.</summary>
    '''<param name='disconnectMode'>Describes how the Add-in is being unloaded.</param>
    '''<param name='custom'>Array of parameters that are host application specific.</param>
    '''<remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub OnDisconnection(ByVal disconnectMode As ext_DisconnectMode, ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnDisconnection
        RemoveHandler _buildEvents.OnBuildBegin, AddressOf OnBuildBegin
        RemoveHandler _buildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigBegin, AddressOf OnBuildProjConfigBegin
    End Sub

    '''<summary>Implements the OnAddInsUpdate method of the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Receives notification that the collection of Add-ins has changed.</summary>
    '''<param name='custom'>Array of parameters that are host application specific.</param>
    '''<remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub OnAddInsUpdate(ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnAddInsUpdate
    End Sub

    '''<summary>Implements the OnStartupComplete method of the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Receives notification that the host application has completed loading.</summary>
    '''<param name='custom'>Array of parameters that are host application specific.</param>
    '''<remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub OnStartupComplete(ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnStartupComplete
    End Sub

    '''<summary>Implements the OnBeginShutdown method of the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Receives notification that the host application is being unloaded.</summary>
    '''<param name='custom'>Array of parameters that are host application specific.</param>
    '''<remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub OnBeginShutdown(ByRef custom As Array) Implements IDTExtensibility2.OnBeginShutdown
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You are probably looking [for this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938.aspx), "How can I run my add-in code in a VSPackage" section.

Answer (score 0):

Packages shouldn't and don't need to implement IDTExtensibility2. There are a couple of solutions:

- Using the automation model (EnvDTE), get the DTE instance as explained in [HOWTO: Get an EnvDTE.DTE instance from a Visual Studio package](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/) and then use DTE.Events.BuildEvents.
- Avoid the automation model and use native VS services, such as [IVsBuildableProjectCfg.AdviseBuildStatusCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildableprojectcfg.advisebuildstatuscallback.aspx) Method and [IVsBuildStatusCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildstatuscallback.aspx)